# Deploying smart contract through Truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I want to know when deploying smart contract using truffle, is there a way to do that without using the migration files?

I won't be requiring the Migration features.

Comment: Do you want to avoid using ``truffle migrate`` at all or do you want to avoid having Migration.sol contract?

Comment: I want to avoid deploying Migration.sol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the -f parameter to start at an arbitrary migration step. In this case, the Migration contract will be ignored.

See https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands#migrate
and https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/503

Comment: -f parameter is not helping. Still 2 contracts are being created.

Comment: Just tested it on my side. It works. I can deploy without a reference to the Migration contract. Did you delete the build folder before the test?